# Logging out from tab, not working for all other tabs

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I've implemented login functionality using custom cookie authentication and its working well.

When I am logging out from one tab it is working find, once use do log out user will redirect to logout screen. but when I have opened more than one tab, user can still access the pages in other tab.

If I do refresh the page in other tab, user is logging out.

It is working only if I manually refresh the page, how can I logout user without refresh the page.

How can I refresh application state.

Answer (score 2):

You have to continuously make an Ajax call to server or refresh the page through meta tag in a fixed interval of time. But it's not a good idea as design. If you use custom cookie follow [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/14996).

Answer (score 1):

In Blazor, every tab runs on a different blazor session Id. Therefore, even when you log out, it will not automatically log you out from the rest of the opened tab. It is the expected behavior. They all are using the same object but with different session ids. Therefore, whatever changes happen in one of the tabs will not reflect in the others.  One way to communicate between multiple tabs is to use local storage. It is the place that all browser tabs share commonly.

In my current Blazor application, I have done something similar. After login, I have added a key-value pair (e.g., date timestamp) into the browser's local storage. Additionally, a setInterval() is registered, which tracks the user's activity. It also checks for the key added at the time of login. Log out from any of the tabs remove the key. When other browser tabs do not find that key, they redirect to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

As [Suprabhat Biswal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70404809/276648) wrote, using the `LocalStorage` can be a good idea to automatically log out from all tabs of the same browser.

If you want to log out from all tabs, from all browsers, from all devices, you can check [RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.server.revalidatingserverauthenticationstateprovider?view=aspnetcore-7.0). The question [Blazor Server Side - How to use RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider to keep checking token expiry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64066276/blazor-server-side-how-to-use-revalidatingserverauthenticationstateprovider-to) may also have some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You should use  `RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider` to sync the authentication state between the circuits, i.e., the connections between the client and the server sides of the Blazor Server application.
[This article](https://auth0.com/blog/blazor-server-and-the-logout-problem/) explains the problem and provides an implementation example.